# JTextPane formatting

Tags: java, swing, styles, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane where I want to add lines and depending on their content have them have a different formatting.

Currently I have this

```
StyleContext context = new StyleContext();
StyledDocument document = new DefaultStyledDocument(context);

Style styleBold = context.getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);
StyleConstants.setBold(styleBold, true);
StyleConstants.setFontSize(styleBold, 18);

Style styleNorm = context.getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);
StyleConstants.setFontSize(styleNorm, 15);

for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
    String tmp = temp.get(i);
    if (tmp.substring(0, 2).equals(COMMENT_PREFIX)) {
        String addThis = " - " + tmp.substring(2);

        try {
            document.insertString(document.getLength(), addThis,
                    styleNorm);
        } //CATCH
    } else if (tmp.substring(0, 2).equals(VERSION_PREFIX)) {
        Date d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String addThis = "Version: " + tmp.substring(2) + " - "
                + d.toString();
        try {
            document.insertString(document.getLength(), addThis,
                    styleBold);
        } //CATCH
    }
    try {
        document.insertString(document.getLength(), "\n", styleNorm);
    } //CATCH
}
```

I took out the catch statements to reduce code size.

However, this formats my entire text with the `styleNorm`. Is this because it's the last called `Style` and they overwrite eachother? If so, how do I fix this?

Comment: Textpane is a pain but you need a Formatter.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that focuses on a single problem.

Answer (score 10):

Also seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7624923/230513), [`TextComponentDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html#eg) shows how to apply a number of `StyleConstants`, including font size, style, alignment and color. The styles may applied either directly to the `Document`, as shown in `initAttributes()`, or via the actions of `StyledEditorKit`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534162/230513).

Addendum: The example below creates three related styles using `SimpleAttributeSet`. Note that `highAlert` alters the color but retains the **bold** attribute inherited from `boldBlue`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15600689/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private void display() throws BadLocationException {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        String s = new Date().toString();
        JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane();
        StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) jtp.getDocument();

        SimpleAttributeSet normal = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(normal, "SansSerif");
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(normal, 16);

        SimpleAttributeSet boldBlue = new SimpleAttributeSet(normal);
        StyleConstants.setBold(boldBlue, true);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(boldBlue, Color.blue);

        SimpleAttributeSet highAlert = new SimpleAttributeSet(boldBlue);
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(highAlert, 18);
        StyleConstants.setItalic(highAlert, true);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(highAlert, Color.red);

        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), s + "\n", normal);
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), s + "\n", boldBlue);
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), s + "\n", highAlert);
        f.add(jtp);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new Test().display();
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 You are really a swing hero. Congrats on exceeding 100K reps.

Comment: how we have combination of **bold** and **italic**. You example basically show bold and italic separately. How i need to print bold and italic for same text.

Comment: @chinna_82 - to set both bold and italic for a SimpleAttributeSet ("sas", for example), you just call both 'StyleConstants.setBold( sas, true )' and 'StyleConstants.setItalic( sas, true )'.