# Set a string to bold in JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I don't want to set the entire text area to bold  but just a selected single line. How would go about doing that?

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15600689/230513) using `JTextPane`.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using a JTextPane instead as there are example solutions for it: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JTextPaneStylesExample6.htm

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it with JTextArea. You can achieve this with [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html).

```
JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
editorPane.setText("<b>This text is bold</b>");
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html),

> A `JTextArea` is a multi-line area that displays plain text.

plain text, in this sense, means every character is formated the same way. There is no way to format some characters differently than other characters.