# Appending a String to a JTextPane

Tags: java, string, swing, append, jtextpane

I have a question.  I am appending a string in a JTextPane, chatWindow, with an insertString, but the only issue is that I don't know how to 'insertString' to my JTextPane.  Here is my code:

```
private void showMessage(final String string){
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        //chatWindow.append(string);
                        //THE BOTTOM METHOD IS USED FOR APPENDING A STRING JTEXTPANE STYLE
                        try
                        {
                            //doc.insertString(0, "Start of text\n", null );
                            //doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "", string );
                            //doc.insertString(int offset, String str, ArributeSet a);

                            //SETTING THE STYLE FOR THE STRING (down below)

                            StyleConstants.setForeground(keyWord, Color.getHSBColor(251, 89, 87));
                            //StyleConstants.setBackground(keyWord, Color.YELLOW);
                            StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, false);

                            doc.insertString(0, string, keyWord);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
```

Where it says:

```
doc.insertString(0, string, keyword);
```

This is where I am appending my string to the chatWindow.  My only issue is that I don't know how 'insertString' specifically to the chatWindow like how I did in the note above the try-catch method:

```
chatWindow.append(string)
```

Does anyone know I could use the 'doc.insertString(0, string, keyword);' to insert the string keyword to chatWindow? The result of doc.insertString doesn't show up on my chatWindow. Thanks.

Comment: What's the type of doc?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Where do I post this SSCCE?

Comment: See the link my friend which Andrew provided.

Comment: Thanks but where do I post it?

Comment: You can edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15600689/230513).

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
chatWindow.getDocument().insertString(0, string, keyword);
```