# JtextPane - Unable to BOLD

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I'm trying to **BOLD** the text in JPane but it not working. If it ***ITALIC*** or **UNDERLINE** its working fine. Below is my code.

```
String strText = "<b><i><u>Testing</b></i></u>";
javax.swing.text.Style style1 = jTextPane1.addStyle("I'm a Style", null);
StyleConstants.setForeground(style1, Color.BLACK);
StyleConstants.setFontSize(style1, 15);
StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style1, "Arial Unicode MS");
if(strText.contains("<b>"))
                        {
                            StyleConstants.setBold(style1, true);
                            strText = strText.replace("<b>", " ");
                            strText = strText.replace("</b>", " ");

                        }
                        if(strText.contains("<i>"))
                        {
                            StyleConstants.setItalic(style1, true);
                            strText = strText.replace("<i>", " ");
                            strText = strText.replace("</i>", " ");

                        }
                        if(strText.contains("<u>"))
                        {
                            StyleConstants.setUnderline(style1, true);
                            strText = strText.replace("<u>", " ");
                            strText = strText.replace("</u>", " ");

                        }
try {
strText = strText.trim();
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), strText, style1);
}
```

The **UNDERLINE** and **ITALIC** working fine meanwhile **BOLD** not working as per expected. The text not **BOLDED**. Please advice where i did mistakes.

Comment: `StyleConstants.setBold(style1, false);`... Do you really mean to set it to `false`?

Comment: hi, I think that the problem isn't in this part of code, it's just good

Comment: There's a complete example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15600689/230513).

Comment: @trashgod I have multiple style in single text. For Eg : Italic and Bold. The example given basically handle font style separately. I have commented in your answer in the example.

Comment: @chinna_82: The styles can be applied independently or combined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15600689/230513), the fragment below illustrates three related styles based on the same font and size:

[image]

```
SimpleAttributeSet normal = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setFontFamily(normal, "SansSerif");
StyleConstants.setFontSize(normal, 16);

SimpleAttributeSet bold = new SimpleAttributeSet(normal);
StyleConstants.setBold(bold, true);

SimpleAttributeSet italic = new SimpleAttributeSet(normal);
StyleConstants.setItalic(italic, true);

doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), s + "\n", normal);
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), s + "\n", bold);
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), s + "\n", italic);
```

Comment: you are printing 3 line with 3 different style. How i do if i want to print 1 line with BOLD and ITALIC at the same time.

Comment: You can repeatedly append the text without a newline to get different styles on the same line.