# How to set the whole (highlighted or not) text in jTextPane back to normal?

Tags: java, swing, text, highlight, jtextpane

I have two methods: `colorText()` and `colorBackground()`. They both color the selected text from`jTextPane`, either its foreground or background. Now I would like to have another method that would set the whole text back to normal (with black foreground and white background).
*How do I do that?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a [`StyledDocument`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15600689/230513), you can invoke `setCharacterAttributes()` with whatever style you want. The example below uses a default `SimpleAttributeSet`, but you can use any `AttributeSet`, such as the ones shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15600689/230513).

[image: before]
[image: after]

```
f.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Clear") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), new SimpleAttributeSet(), true);
    }
}), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```