# Passing a parameter through constructor

Tags: java, swing, decoupling, loose-coupling

First I will present a quick outline of a somewhat tightly coupled classes (though not the worst possible case):

```
class setUpGUI {

   ...
   JTextField output = new JTextField();
   ...
   CountTimer ct;
   ...

   public void setOtputText(String text) {
       output.setText(text);

   public startTimer() {
      ct = new CountTimer();
   }

   ...
}

class CountTimer implements ActionListener {

    private String text = "";
    private gui = new SetUpGUI();
    ...

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ...
        gui.setOtputText(text);
        ...
    }
```

My question is about the second snippet (in comparison with the first and on its own):

```
// functionally equivalent to com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasText
interface HasText {

    String getText();
    void setText(String text);

}

class setUpGUI {

   ...
   JTextField output = new JTextField();
   ...
   CountTimer ct;
   ...

   public void setOtputText(String text) {
       output.setText(text);

   public startTimer() {
      ct = new CountTimer(output);
   }

   ...
}

class CountTimer implements ActionListener {

    private String text = "";
    private HasText txtComp;
    ...

    CountTimer(txtComp) {
        ...
        this.txtComp = txtComp;
        ...
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ...
        txtComp.setText(text);
        ...
    }
}
```

I believe that the second design can be considered a *loose coupling*, since instead of using a `setter` it passes a reference through constructor and at the same time defines its own `HasText` interface (since Swing does not seem to have one and I didn't find a common parent of `JtextComponent` and `JLabel` that has `setText()` method).  Would you agree?

What is the general attitude towards passing a parameter via constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Your second example passes a textual view component to a class that implements `ActionListener`. Instead, consider a class that extends [`AbstractAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to allow centralized handling of action events. In the particular case of a text component, [`TextAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/TextAction.html) provides access to the focused text component and the underlying `Document` model to which the `JTextComponent` listens. As concrete examples, outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15181906/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7624923/230513), such pre-defined actions are used throughout the `EditorKit` hierarchy.

For periodic actions, such as might occur in response to a timer, consider letting the `ActionListener` update the text component's `Document`; the listening view will update itself  automatically in response. In this case, the listener's constructor would receive a reference to the text component's model.

Comment: My 2nd class implements ActionListener for a Swing `Timer` (not text field).  JTextField is used simply as a component that can hold a text (its *editability* is errlelevant here).  Could've been a `JLabel` instead.

Comment: The mechanism is the same: let the timer's listener update the _view_ component's _model_, and the listening _view_ will update itself automatically in response.