# Implementation of AbstractAction in the MVC model

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, abstract-action

I'm developing a **MVC** Java **Swing** application, which will offer the user at least a dozen of different actions. Some of these actions will trigger execution of a `SwingWorker` object, while others are pretty simple (or common). I started with the approach discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066015/how-to-manage-view-updates-from-controllers-in-a-java-swing-app), but I modified it in order to avoid to define an implementation of the `AbstractAction` class for any "common" action. This is the solution I implemented:

The **Action** enum class defines my "common" actions:

```
public enum Action {
//               label          mnemonic            modelObject  modelMethod
EXIT            ("Exit"     ,   KeyEvent.VK_E   ,   "SubModel", "openExitView")
,FLAG_1         ("Flag 1"   ,   KeyEvent.VK_1   ,   "Options",  "setFlag_1")
,FLAG_2         ("Flag 2"   ,   KeyEvent.VK_2   ,   "Options",  "setFlag_2")
,HELP           ("Help"     ,   KeyEvent.VK_L   ,   "SubModel", "openHelpView")
,ABOUT          ("About"    ,   KeyEvent.VK_A   ,   "SubModel", "openAboutView");
```

Then, in the **Controller** class, I added this method:

```
public AbstractAction getAction(final Action action) {

AbstractAction actionImpl = new AbstractAction(action.label) {
    {
        putValue(AbstractAction.MNEMONIC_KEY, action.mnemonic);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        model.executeAction(action);
    }
}; 

return actionImpl;
```

}

so I get the actions like following (in the Controller) and I assign them to the target Swing components:

```
private AbstractAction exitAction = getAction(Action.EXIT);

private AbstractAction flag_1Action = getAction(Action.FLAG_1);
private AbstractAction flag_2Action = getAction(Action.FLAG_2);

private AbstractAction helpAction = getAction(Action.HELP);
private AbstractAction aboutAction = getAction(Action.ABOUT);

private AbstractAction complexAction = new ComplexAction("Complex");
...
    view.setExitAction(exitAction);
    view.setAboutAction(aboutAction);
    view.setHelpAction(helpAction);
    ...
```

where `ComplexAction` is a full implementation of `AbstractAction`, which is just an example of management of an action non listed in the enum class (because it's not a "common" action) but something deserving a custom full implementation.

Finally the "general purpose" `executeAction` method in the **Model** is responsible for dispatching the action to the specific sub-model class:

```
    public void executeAction(Action action) {

      Object obj = getModelInstance(action.modelObject);
      if (obj == null) return;

      Method method = null;
      try {
        method = obj.getClass().getMethod(action.modelMethod);
        ...
```

where `getModelInstance` just retrieves an instance of the target sub-model object from a model factory, given the model's class name listed in the enum.

Everything works fine, but I'm not convinced of this pattern: is this not **boilerplate code**? Are there some J2EE objects achieving the same results by writing **less code**? I have the feeling this is a very common pattern, and it seems strange to me that there isn't a better way do implement the MVC pattern using `AbstractAction`.

Comment: You could generalize events through a sort of EventBus where you can register to events by a String, and then trigger events passing a String and an EventObject (superclass of ActionEvent).  Your action listeners do nothing more than trigger the EventBus with a unique event name identifier that all listeners will receive notification.  It allows you to disconnect the actual event generator and where the action needs to occur.

Comment: Voting to re-open based on update, but the question is still very broad; see also [*Examples of GoF Design Patterns in Java's core libraries*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1673841/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Create an abstract class that *contains* implementations of [`Action`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html). The exact formulation depends on your domain, but [`EditorKit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/EditorKit.html) may serve as an example. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414137/what-are-editorkits-in-jtextcomponents-and-what-is-their-job/23420145#23420145), concrete editor kits "export useful `Action` classes that operate on the `Document` model common to text components." More discussion may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22106195/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15181906/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7624923/230513).

Comment: Re [update 2](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35479248/revisions), `DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction` is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34830519/230513).