# Fix style of DefaultStyledDocument

Tags: java, swing, styleddocument

I am wondering if it is possible to fix the style of `StyledDocument` in java. According to my observation, the style will change depending on style of previous position.

So I can key in the content with my defined style without being affected by the style of previous position.

Many thanks for the response!

Comment: A counterexample is examined in this possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7624247/230513).

Comment: Many thanks to "trashgod", this example is what I need.